# Qt Creator not working with VirtualBox 3D Acceleration

Tags: virtualbox, qt-creator, 3d

I am running vanilla 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in latest VirtualBox (5.1.12) under Windows 7.  I have VB's latest *Guest Additions* installed.  I have switched VB's *Display* **Enable 3D Acceleration** on.  I have an NVidia GeForce GTS 450.  The output from `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` is all "yes", FWIW.

All seems to be well, until I run Qt Creator (3.0.1).  The screen comes up OK, with the window "furniture" borders and the central pane.  But then I can interact with the window borders OK, but the main central pane stays fixed on the desktop (e.g. if I "minimize" Qt via the icon in the window border), no menus etc. are shown over it, and the whole thing is unusable.

Is this a VirtualBox, Ubuntu or Qt Creator issue?  Does this happen to others of you?  Any suggestions (other than switch 3D Acceleration off,which I have done for now, and then it works OK)?

Comment: it also happens to me under virtualbox mac hypervizor + linux guest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- disable 3d acceleration from virtualbox settings and boot the system
- In Qt Creator, go to Help → About Plugins…
- Uncheck Qt Creator –> Welcome
- exit Qt Creator, shutdown system and enable 3d acceleration
- It should work now after reboot

I got the solution from https://dmitryfrank.com/blog/2015/0716_qt_creator_in_virtualbox_with_windows_guest_os

Comment: Thank you. I agree this fixes the "freeze". *However*, with no "Welcome" I can no longer just click to open my projects. And when I manually find the project and reload it, it no longer remembers which windows I had open in it last. So all in all, a pain. Besides, if this means with 3D Acceleration I cannot use (other) Qt Widgets, I think I'd better manage without 3D after all!

Answer (score 1):

Reboot not needed:

Start qtcreator using:

```
./qtcreator -noload Welcome -noload QmlDesigner -noload QmlProfiler
```

in QT creator folder (i.e. `C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin`). Then you can disable the welcome plugin without reboot.

see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325095/qt-creator-hangs-in-ubuntu-virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, and deactivating either 3D or the Welcome screen was not an option for me.
I just discovered by chance however that uninstalling the VBox-Guest-Additions works:

```
sudo /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.1.22/uninstall.sh
```

Tried this in Ubuntu16 with the latest version of qt-creator (4.2.2).
I'm not sure if this is a Qt-Creator or VBox bug!

Comment: I'm not at all sure what the consequences of this are --- does this throw the baby out with the bath water? e.g. can you still access USBs? does this deactivate 3D anyway?  I think I tried this in the past and ran into problems, so had to enable it.

Comment: ...yes you were absolutely right! I checked with "/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p" and 3D was disabled anyway. So I guess that de-installing the Guest-Additions is the same as un-checking the Enable 3D box!

Comment: can anyone confirm that Qt-Creator 4.3.0 fixed this? seems to work for me

Comment: No, not according to me.  All versions of Qt Creator are known not to work correctly with "hardware" 3D Acceleration as supplied via VirtualBox (I think it's an Open GL issue).  I (believe I) am using the latest Qt Creator, and I still have to switch off 3D in VirtualBox to get consistently correct behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling **Line Annotations** in **Text Editor** settings. It worked for me.

I was having similar problems, but mostly when I open my code with lots of warnings scrolling through that code used to freeze the qt creator and also the Ubuntu VBox guest for an awful while.